# How to Seperate a variable which have string and number both?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this code

```
a = list(map(str, input('Enter: ').split(',')))
# print(a)
m = []
n = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if str(a[i]).isdigit():
        m.append(a[i])
    else:
        n.append(a[i])
print(m, n)
```

input that it take from user like

```
N2 S3 E6 Q2 W9 N6
```

Output required:

```
[2, 3, 6, 2, 9, 6]
[N,S,E,Q,W,N]
```

[Output][I get from above code]
Please help me if you know

Comment: If you have a string like `"N2 S3 E6"`, then you do `"N2 S3 E6".split(',')`, what does it give you? What did you *expect* it to give you and why?

Comment: actually i am working on large assignment , so that i need to read string as input and split them with number and strings .

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't address what I asked you at all.

Comment: replace your `a = ...` with `a = "N2 S3 E6 Q2 W9 N6"` - run your code. Refine it. `a = list(map(str, input('Enter: ').split(',')))` with your current input makes no sense - even with other input it makes no sense as _input() returns a string already , `split()` returns a list of strings - so map(str, ...) is senseless

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re

text = 'N2 S3 E6 Q2 W9 N6'

numbers = re.findall(r'(?<=[A-Z])\d+', text)
letters = re.findall(r'[A-Z](?=\d+)', text)
```

Comment: If you are going to just drop regex on a question like this, you really should elaborate a little. That being said, these seem overcomplicated for the job at hand, why the postitive look-ahead/look-behind? Why not just `re.findall(r"\d+", text)` and `re.findall(r"[A-Z]", text)` (or even `re.findall(r"\D+", text)`)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it seems that the user can input anything, so narrowing down the findall could be beneficial